# How do I solve this error, its a cipher for shifting 13 letters.

Tags: python-3.x

Why Do I Get This Error?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in 
IndexError: string index out of range

On this Code

```
Cipher = input("Enter encrypted text:")
length = len(Cipher)
start = 0
decrypt=""
while length!=Cipher: 
  asc=ord(Cipher[int(start)]) #String index out of range
  if asc <=95:
    decrypt=decrypt+Cipher[start]
  elif asc >95 and asc <=110:
    num = asc
    num=num+13
    decrypt=decrypt+chr(num)
  elif asc>110 and asc<=122:
    num = asc
    num=num-13
    decrypt=decrypt+chr(num)
  else:
    decrypt=decrypt+""
  start=start+asc
print("DONE!")
```

How do I Solve It?

Comment: What are you doing there in line 5? Comparing the length of a string to the string itsself? That doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

```
Cipher = list(input("Enter encrypted text:"))
length = len(Cipher)
start = 0
decrypt=""
while start != length: 
  asc=ord(Cipher[start])
  if asc <=95:
    decrypt=decrypt+Cipher[start]
  elif asc >95 and asc <=110:
    num = asc
    num=num+13
    decrypt=decrypt+chr(num)
  elif asc>110 and asc<=122:
    num = asc
    num=num-13
    decrypt=decrypt+chr(num)
  start=start+1

print("DONE! Result: " + decrypt)
```

You can try it here: https://repl.it/Nn05/0